# How do you talk to someone to reopen a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

A question of mine on Stack Overflow is voted as mostly opinion based and therefore closed.

In my opinion, it is not "opinion based" and is a specific question about how/why something is used.

It appears that once one person has flagged your question, it is doomed because others will follow suit. I don't know how to "defend" my question. Really I would like to post a message to those who have voted against it to ask what the problem really is and how I can resolve it.

There is an option to edit your question, but as I say I think I ask a specific question so I don't know how to update it.

My question here is, how can I ask the people who voted it closed what the issue is? and if I can't ask them directly, what can I do?

Comment: *cough* link to your question? *cough*

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448874/centralised-message-routing-class-good-or-bad-design

Comment: "Is this good or bad design?" --> I can see why people would think it is opinion based.

Comment: Your question is either _opinion based_ or way _too broad_.

Comment: Yeah - I would go with 'too broad'.  Not enough requirement specification means that a design recommendation would be impossible to justify.  Then again, Serge's answer was quite good..

Comment: If you have a strong case you could drop a re-open request in the [SO Close voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: Thanks all, so too broad I can understand, its not a specific line of code. But I am just trying to ask when a "thing" can be used. Also.... @whoever, -9?! - seriously?, is this question that bad? :o  .... shheshhh, tough crowd ; )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448874/centralised-message-routing-class-good-or-bad-design) is about *"good or bad design"*.

Specifically this line:

> So I can't see any good reasons for a centralised message class "pattern". Can anyone give good reasons for it (or against)?

Asks for opinionated answers.

As the reason of closure describes:

> Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

I honestly can't find any reason why that closure reason would not apply to your question.

---

To answer your actual question:

If a person that close-voted your question has also commented on the question, you can @notify them in a comment. Other than that, there is no good way to contact a user on SO about that specific question.

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus, this is a good answer, even if its not the one I wanted! : )